# Return a value if no rows match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

The `[authorityID] (TinyInt)` column  will never be `null`.

What I want is to return a `15` if there are no rows. With the query below I get nothing if there are no rows:

```
select top 1 isnull([authorityID],15) 
from [docAuthority] with (nolock) 
where [grpID] = 0 and [sID] = 42
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  authorityId = isnull(( SELECT   [authorityID]
                               FROM     [docAuthority] WITH ( NOLOCK )
                               WHERE    [grpID] = 0
                                        AND [sID] = 42
                             ), 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, if the query returns no rows, there's nothing to apply the `isnull` on. One dirty trick is to use `union all` and (ab)use the `top` construct:

```
SELECT TOP 1 authorityID
FROM   (SELECT authorityID
        FROM   [docAuthority] WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE  [grpID] = 0 AND [sID] = 42
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 15) t
```

Comment: Not as slick as I would hope for but I don't think there is anything better.  Let me give it a couple hours for a trick before I accept this answer.  P.S.  Since I am reading into .NET I will do it there if there is not a more direct way to do in TSQL.